# Display Lower Tf MACD on Higher TF using arrays

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to display lower tf macd on higher tf chart using arrays. I have done half the way, but stuck up in plotting macd using arrays. the histo's are somewhat achieved but not exact in macd logic, but other macd and signal line plotting I have no idea about it in array

[image]

The Histo are awkard as you can see in the picture ...my bad i dont know how to plot macd

```
//@version=5
indicator("LTF Candle",overlay = true,max_bars_back = 500, max_boxes_count = 500)

// ~~ Inputs {
tf       = input.timeframe("5","Timeframe", group="Lower Timeframe Candles")
numb     = input.int(20,"Amount of Candles",minval=0, maxval=100, group="Lower Timeframe Candles")
dn_col   = input.color(color.new(color.red,10), title="Dn", inline="Candles", group="Lower Timeframe Candles")
dn_wick  = input.color(color.new(color.red,0), title="Wick", inline="Candles", group="Lower Timeframe Candles")
up_col   = input.color(color.new(color.lime,10), title="Up",inline="Candles", group="Lower Timeframe Candles")
up_wick  = input.color(color.new(color.lime,0), title="Wick", inline="Candles", group="Lower Timeframe Candles")
Range    = input.bool(true,"Range High/Low", inline="range", group="Range")
Mid      = input.bool(true,"Range Mid", inline="range", group="Range")
high_col = input.color(color.red, title="High", inline="range 1", group="Range")
low_col  = input.color(color.lime, title="Low",inline="range 1", group="Range")
mid_col  = input.color(color.rgb(20, 69, 246), title="Mid",inline="range 1", group="Range")
loc      = input.int(-20,"Location", group="Location Settings")

// ~~ Table Inputs {
showTable      = input.bool(true,title="Show Table", inline="tbl", group="Table")
TblSize        = input.string(size.normal,title="",options=[size.auto,size.tiny,size.small,size.normal,size.large,size.huge],inline="tbl", group="Table")
pos            = input.string(position.top_right, title="",options =[position.top_right,position.top_center,
 position.top_left,position.bottom_right,position.bottom_center,position.bottom_left,position.middle_right,position.middle_left],inline="tbl", group="Table")
textcolor      = input.color(color.white, title="Text",inline="tbl_col", group="Table")
bgcolor        = input.color(color.new(color.blue,30), title="Bg",inline="tbl_col", group="Table")
//~~~}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}

// ~~ LTF Error Message {
tfs = str.tonumber(tf)
if str.tostring(tf) == "1D"
    tfs := 1440 
error = str.tonumber(timeframe.period)<tfs
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}

//********************MACD Calculation*************************
source = close
fastLength = input.int(12, minval=1)//default=12-9
slowLength = input.int(26, minval=1)//default=26-23
signalLength = input.int(9, minval=1)//default=9-7

fastMA = ta.ema(source, fastLength) 
slowMA = ta.ema(source, slowLength) 

//****************************end ***************************//

// ~~ UDT {
type Candle
    array<line> macd2
    array<line> signal2
    array<box> hist2
    //array<float> hl

type LTF
    array<float> macd1
    array<float> signal1
    array<float> hist1
    //array<float> c
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}
var float [] arr = na

// ~~ Variables {
b = bar_index
var candle  = Candle.new(array.new<line>(numb),array.new<line>(numb),array.new<box>(numb))
var ltfData = LTF.new(array.new<float>(numb),array.new<float>(numb),array.new<float>(numb))//,array.new<float>(numb))

macd = ta.ema(source, fastLength) - ta.ema(source, slowLength)
signal = ta.ema(macd, signalLength)
hist = macd - signal

var float [] ltfmacd = na
var float [] ltfsignal = na
var float [] ltfhist = na


ltfmacd := request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid,tf,ta.ema(source, fastLength) - ta.ema(source, slowLength))
ltfsignal := request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid,tf,ta.ema(macd, signalLength))
ltfhist := request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid,tf,macd - signal)

//ltfO        = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, tf, open)
//ltfH        = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, tf, high)
//ltfL        = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, tf, low)
//ltfC        = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, tf, close)
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}

// ~~ Code {
//~~Save Previous Candle Data
if timeframe.change(timeframe.period)
    if ltfData.macd1.size()>numb
        while ltfData.macd1.size()>numb
            ltfData.macd1.shift()
            ltfData.signal1.shift()
            ltfData.hist1.shift()
            
    ltfData.macd1.concat(ltfmacd)
    ltfData.signal1.concat(ltfsignal)
    ltfData.hist1.concat(ltfhist)
    

//~~ Plot Candles
if ltfData.macd1.size()>=numb
    d = loc
    for i=ltfData.macd1.size()-numb to ltfData.macd1.size()-1
        candle.macd2.shift().delete()
        candle.signal2.shift().delete()
        candle.hist2.shift().delete()
        //candle.hl.shift()
        //candle.hl.shift()
        o = ltfData.macd1.get(i)
        h = ltfData.signal1.get(i)
        l = ltfData.hist1.get(i)
        //c = ltfData.c.get(i) 
        // This area where am unable to plot the regular macd 
        candle.macd2.push(line.new(b+d*2+1+loc,math.max(o,h),b+d*2+1+loc,h,color=o>h?dn_col:up_col))
        candle.signal2.push(line.new(b+d*2+1+loc,math.max(o,h),b+d*2+1+loc,h,color=o>h?dn_col:up_col))
        candle.hist2.push(box.new(b+d*2+loc,l > 0 ? l+high : high,b+d*2+2+loc, l < 0 ? high - (l*-1) : high,color(na),bgcolor= o<0?dn_col:up_col))    
        d += 2
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}
// Also i need to check conditions for strategy like Hist > 0 and hist > hist[1] and macd > signal or macd <= signal in 1h tf
//Just like regular macd pls help me on this bro
```